# Passing a void* by reference

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, void-pointers

Why can't I pass a `void*` by reference? The compiler allows me to declare a function with the following signature:

```
static inline void FreeAndNull(void*& item)
```

But when I try to call it, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'FreeAndNull' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'uint8_t *' to 'void *&'
```

Casting it to `void*` doesn't work either

Also, are there any workarounds?

Comment: The existence of this function in your code means your code could be improved. You shouldn't be deleting things manually, and you shouldn't care what the value of the pointer is afterward. Use a smart pointer instead.

Comment: @GMan: Good advice, but the situation was simplified for the purposes of this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a void * by reference, you have to pass an actual void *, not an uint8_t *.

Try this instead:

```
template<typename T> inline void FreeAndNull(T * & V) { free(V); V = 0; }
```

EDIT: Modified sample to better reflect the OP's function name, and to address @6502's entirely correct comment.

Comment: +1, cool! But now I'm curious: Why doesn't the cast work in the OP's example?

Comment: This seems to me a risky implementation. I suppose that the OP didn't allocate a single `uint8_t` element, so using `delete` instead of `delete[]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Cameron- See my answer below for why the cast doesn't work.  The technical version is that it produces an rvalue where an lvalue is needed, but the intuitive reason is that it's unsafe.

Comment: @template - that's right, but your answer doesn't even mention lvalue/rvalue.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is yes, you can pass a `void*` by reference, and the error you're getting is unrelated to that.  The problem is that if you have a function that takes `void*` by reference, then you can only pass in variables that actually are `void*`s as a parameter.  There's a good reason for this.  For example, suppose you have this function:

```
void MyFunction(void*& ptr) {
    ptr = malloc(137); // Get a block of raw memory
}

int* myIntArray;
MyFunction(myIntArray); // Error- this isn't legal!
```

The above code is illegal because of the indicated call, and for good reason.  If we could pass in `myIntArray` into `MyFunction`, it would get reassigned to point to a buffer of type `void*` that isn't an `int` array.  Consequently, on return from the function your `int*` would be pointing at an array of type `void*`, subverting the type system.  This isn't to say that C++ has a strong type system - it doesn't - but if you're going to subvert it you have to explicitly put some casts in.

You similarly can't do this:

```
void MyFunction(void*& ptr) {
    ptr = malloc(137); // Get a block of raw memory
}

int* myIntArray;
MyFunction((void*)myIntArray); // Error- this isn't legal!
```

As a good reference as to why you can't do this, think about this code:

```
void OtherFunction(int& myInt) {
    myInt = 137;
}

double myDouble;
OtherFunction((int)myDouble); // Also error!
```

This isn't legal because if you tried passing in a `double` into a function that took an `int&`, then since `int` and `double` have fundamentally different binary representations, you'd end up clobbering the bits of the `double` with meaningless data.  If this cast were to be legal, it would be possible to do Bad Things like this.

So in short, yes, you can take in a `void* &`, but if you do you have to pass in real `void*`s.  As Erik pointed out above, if you want to free and zero a pointer templates are the way to go.

If you really do want to pass in a `uint_8*` into this your function, you could do so like this:

```
uint_8* uPtr = /* ... */
void* ptr = uPtr;
FreeAndNull(ptr);
uPtr = (uint_8*) ptr;
```

This requires explicit casting to tell the compiler "Yes, I know this may be unsafe, but I'm going to do it anyway."

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, this makes perfect sense now. lvalues rule and rvalues drool!

Comment: @Cameron, templatetypedef: btw, casting it with `(void*&)` would've "worked" (as in it would have compiled, i'm not sure if using it afterwards is UB)

Comment: @Crazy Eddie- (I assume you downvoted this; ignore this if you didn't) Can you explain what's wrong with this answer?  I want this to be useful, so anything I can do to clarify would be most appreciated.

Comment: See my answer and my comment to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Casting to void* doesn't work for a reason much simpler than what is being explained elsewhere: casting creates rvalues unless you explicitly specify a reference.  You can't pass an rvalue off as a non-const reference.

Prove it?  Try this:

```
void fun(void * &) {}
int main() {
    int * x;
    void * x2 = x;
    fun(x);
}
```

If it's appropriate for you use, try this:

```
void fun(void * const&);
```

Now not only does casting work, its implicit.

Casting to reference can be dangerous.  It does actually cause your code to compile but I won't speak to its behavior:

```
void fun(void *&) { }
int main() {
    int * x;
    fun((void*&)x);
}
```

My bet is that this will do very-bad-things(tm) since you're actually doing a reinterpret_cast here rather than a static cast.

Comment: "casting creates rvalues" is not neccessarily right. `(void*&)x` produces an lvalue.

Comment: It would appear passing as a const-ref is definitely not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Fred - since appearances can be deceiving, I don't see your point.